# JS changing menu class not working in IE 8

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8

I have a `.js` code as under:

```js
var x = jQuery(window).innerHeight();
jQuery(document).scroll(function() {
    if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() >= x) {
        jQuery('#nav').removeClass('nav').addClass('topfix_nav');
    } else {
        jQuery('#nav').removeClass('topfix_nav').addClass('nav');
    }
});
```

CSS:

for nav class has common property for menu

```css
.topfix_nav {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    height: 60px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0%;
    right: 0%;
    background-color: #FFF;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

It works in Chrome and Mozilla but IE 8 did not chang the class and does not give any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
```

instead of:

```
jQuery(document).scroll(function() {
```

Comment: not working same result.
and please see code on scroll its already document.

Comment: You need to change `document` to `window`